# Scheme theoretic dual of $\mathbb P^n_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

Consider an algebraically closed field $k$, and define $\mathbb P^n_k:=\textrm{Proj}(k[T_0,\ldots,T_n])$. In some algebraic geometry books I see the notation ${(\mathbb P^n_k)}^\vee$ that is referred as "*the dual projective space*" without any other precisation.

Now I'm confused: $\mathbb P^n_k$ is a scheme and I don't understand what is the formal meaning of its "dual". Maybe hyperplane divisors are involved?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to add to Zhen Lin's precise answer: yes, hyperplane divisors are involved. The points of $(\mathbf P^n)^\vee$ are the hyperplanes in $\mathbf P^n$.

Comment: This intuitively must be true thanks to the analogy with the classical projective space, but formally I don't understand the definition.

Comment: The definition of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is not 100% correct (use $n+1$ variables).

Comment: Yeah you're right

Answer (score 4):

If you have a $k$-vector space $V$ you can form the symmetric algebra on $V$,
$$\operatorname{Sym} V = k \oplus V \oplus V^{\otimes 2} / S_2 \oplus V^{\otimes 3} / S_3 \oplus \cdots $$
and it is clearly a graded $k$-algebra. We define $\mathbb{P} (V) = \operatorname{Proj} \operatorname{Sym} V$. The dual of $\mathbb{P} (V)$ is just $\mathbb{P} (V^\vee)$.

Comment: here $V=k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$?

Comment: Typically $V$ is finite dimensional. If $\dim V = n + 1$ then $\mathbb{P} (V) \cong \mathbb{P}_k^n$.

Comment: Ok, and which is the connection with the hyperplane divisors?

Comment: A point of the dual projective space is an equivalence class of linear forms on the original vector space, which defines a hyperplane in the usual way.

Comment: @ZhenLin: The description of the symmetric algebra is not correct.